# Excel; Conditional formatting Date/Time between two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I have two columns, for example Column A and B with the below style of set up.

What I am wanting to do is to highlight both columns in a colour based on certain parameters.

For example: If Column B is due to occur AFTER Column A - no colour. If Column B is due to occur at the SAME TIME as Column A - Highlight both cells in yellow. If Column B is due to occur BEFORE Column A - Highlight in Red.

Please see below examples of the kind of data I would be working with, and then below it an example of what it would look like should the conditional formatting colour it in correctly.

Thank you.

[Base Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7JbK.png)
[Completed Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waBDw.png)

Comment: Impossible to understand your data when no explanation given about 1700LT, 1800LT, 1900LT. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, figured out that 1800LT = 1800 hours, Local Time(?)

You will need to create two conditional formatting rules. One for each of your conditions.

Conditional formatting > Manage Rules... > New Rule... > Use a formula to determine which cells to format.

Rule 1, set color to Red:

```
=IF($B1<$A1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Rule 2, set color to Yellow:

```
=IF($A1=$B1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey, Yeah LT being Local time. This is basically what I was after, thankyou! Just one thing if you're aware how to do it; is there a way to specify it not to treat an empty cell in column B a "Less than" column A? For example if there's "01-Feb 1800LT" in cell A10, but B10 is empty, I don't want it to colour the cells etc.

Comment: Look into AND, NOT and ISNUMBER

Comment: Fantastic - got that working. Sorry to be awkward again though; one thing I am running into is it will search for the date yes and sort that, but not ref month. 

So for example, it thinks that 01-Feb is before 29-Jan - any clues on a fix for that at all? If not no biggie!

Comment: Please clarify what is shown for date in formula bar. Make sure years are the same.

Comment: I might be being dense, not had a go at this in Excel before. How do you mean by date in formula bar?

At the moment I have the this (https://puu.sh/IG0nV/b042b421dc.png) data to work with for example, and currently utilizing this (https://puu.sh/IG0os/b012e78501.png , =IF($C1 <> "", IF($E1 <> "", IF($E1=$C1, TRUE, FALSE))) , =IF($E1<>"",IF($E1<$C1, TRUE, FALSE)) ) conditional formatting.

Comment: The formula bar has the little 'fx' next to the formula you type in. Or edit the format so you can see the year.
Why not do a test in column G? `=E1>C1` and see what you get.

Comment: Using the test column as you stated this ( https://puu.sh/IGoNH/60dd92a3ea.png ) shows my results. So as expected, it's thinking 01-Feb is before 29-Jan. All years are listed the same; as there's no year input (only day-month time).

Comment: I get the sense 29 and 01 are year. I don't know what you mean "All years are listed the same". There is no "day-month time" in Excel. Right-click on cell>Format cells...>Number tab>Click custom... what is the code in the box?